# Google DLP takes a long time to process

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, data-loss, pii, google-cloud-dlp

I tried using Google DLP (in particular inspecting text - string of less than 80 characters) and I find that requests take over two seconds to fulfill.

Is this normal? Is there a way to reduce the processing time?

Comment: do all your requests take the same amount of time? Have you had the API process requests quicker?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a sample of your request (minus the sensitive data of course)?